# upload image in laravel 8 - API

Tags: laravel, api, upload, polymorphism, relation

I want to upload image for my posts and have polymorphism relation one to one (because I have other tables and they need image too ) between posts and images

And when I want to send request and store the image in database , I get this error:

`BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\Image::move()`

I'm creating an API so :

My postman :

[image]

My relations :

`Image model` :

```
class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'image'
    ];

    public function imageable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

`Post model` :

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use \Conner\Tagging\Taggable;


    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id' ,
        'category_id' ,
        'title' ,
        'body' ,
        'study_time',
        'likes',
        'status',
        'tags',
    ];

    public function image(){
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class , 'imageable');
    }

}
```

And the `PostController` , `store()` method :

```
    public function store(Request $request )
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'user_id'=>'required',
            'category_id'=>'required',
            'title' => 'required|max:150|unique:posts',
            'body' => 'required',
            'study_time'=>'required',
            'tags'=>'nullable|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'error']);
        }

        //separate tags
        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);


        $image = new Image;
        $getImage = $request->file('image');
        $imageName = time().'.'.$getImage->extension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);



        $post = Post::create($data);

        $post->image()->save($image);

        //save tags
        $post->tag($tags);


        return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "successfull",
        "data" => $post
        ]);
    }
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `$getImage->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);` becouse `$request->file('image');` this is a `File::class` object and it has `move()` function to call

Comment: So how do I move it?

Comment: `$getImage->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);` use this

Comment: and now my problem is saving in `image` table .. when i change it to your code and send request  , gives this error : `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'image' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: `$post->image()->save($imageName);` you need to fix this too

Comment: i tried before .. gives error : `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model,`

Comment: `$imageName` this is image path store in `image` Model

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many please learn this for that

Comment: thank you. i solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a month of this challenge, I was finally able to solve it :}

To make the code better and cleaner, I added another column to my image table : `path`

it's for saving path of image , and another column : `image`

and i added the `path` to my fillable in `Image` model and i edited the code to this :

```
public function store(Request $request )
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'user_id'=>'required',
            'category_id'=>'required',
            'title' => 'required|max:150|unique:posts',
            'body' => 'required',
            'study_time'=>'required',
            'tags'=>'nullable|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'error']);
        }

        //separate tags
        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

        $image = new Image;
        $getImage = $request->image
        $imageName = time().'.'.$getImage->extension();
        $imagePath = public_path(). '/images/posts';

        $image->path = $imagePath;
        $image->image = $imageName;

        $getImage->move($imagePath, $imageName);

        $post = Post::create($data);

        $post->image()->save($getImage);

        $post->tag($tags);


        return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "successfully",
        "data" => $post
        ]);
    }
```